# Is it possible to get the network to accept a partially signed multisig transaction?

Tags: multi-signature

I tried to send a half signed multisig transaction to the testnet but it got rejected.

I think this is by design but has anyone some hard facts on this?

**EDIT:**
I think https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0010 was the case I was looking for.

Comment: What could it possibly do with the transaction?!

Comment: Forward it to another node that signs it. But i think https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0010 is what I was looking for.

Comment: Sure, if it somehow knew there was some other node that would sign it, but how could it know that?

Comment: Why does it need to know another node signs it?

Comment: Because if another node is not going to sign it, then there's no point in forwarding it. Anyone can create an unlimited number of incompletely-signed transactions and nodes must not be willing to do unbounded work.

Comment: Anyone could create an unlimited number of signed transactions that contain no fee and point to his own address.

Comment: No, because he can only have a finite number of outputs that can be transferred with no fee, and each such transaction consumes at least one old transaction output. (If this were true, Bitcoin would be broken. Bitcoin is not broken.)

Comment: The same applies to the partially signed multi sig transactions.

Comment: No. There is no limit to the number of partially-signed multi-sig transactions you can form. You can create any number of such transactions that spend the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The network will only forward transactions that are valid. That is they only claim so far unclaimed outputs and contain all the necessary signature scripts. Your transaction does not contain valid signature scripts, hence it's not valid and will be dropped by the nodes in the network.